# Leiningen throws clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm a Java developer taking first steps with Clojure. I have put together a simple project using **Leiningen 2.8.1** and **Clojure 1.9.0**. The code of my project is available [here](https://github.com/foundationer/takeaways).

My problem is very simple. When I run "lein" from the console I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named
 at clojure.core$name.invokeStatic (core.clj:1546)
    clojure.core$name.invoke (core.clj:1540)
    leiningen.core.project$absolutize_path.invokeStatic (project.clj:453)
    leiningen.core.project$absolutize_path.invoke (project.clj:452)
    clojure.core.protocols$iter_reduce.invokeStatic (protocols.clj:49)
    clojure.core.protocols$fn__6744.invokeStatic (protocols.clj:75)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn (protocols.clj:75)
    clojure.core.protocols$fn__6684$G__6679__6697.invoke (protocols.clj:13)
    clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic (core.clj:6545)
    clojure.core$reduce.invoke (core.clj:6527)
    leiningen.core.project$absolutize_paths.invokeStatic (project.clj:463)
    leiningen.core.project$absolutize_paths.invoke (project.clj:462)
    leiningen.core.project$init_profiles.invokeStatic (project.clj:887)
    leiningen.core.project$init_profiles.doInvoke (project.clj:865)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    leiningen.core.project$init_project.invokeStatic (project.clj:950)
    leiningen.core.project$init_project.invoke (project.clj:942)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:1023)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:1020)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invokeStatic (project.clj:1024)
    leiningen.core.project$read.invoke (project.clj:1020)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__4734.invoke (main.clj:416)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:411)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:408)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:397)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:375)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:314)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:310)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:421)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:384)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:421)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:383)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
```

It doesn't matter if I run `lein` or `lein test`, the result is the same. And I don't see any reference to my code in the stack trace, so I'm clueless.
Any ideas of what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project.clj file is missing a closing bracket [here](https://github.com/foundationer/takeaways/blob/1067043378800261147457830baab93c09dd19e4/project.clj#L9).

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
               [mount "0.1.11"] ;; delete extra bracket
               [midje "1.9.1"]
               [com.datomic/datomic-free "0.9.5656"]] ;; add closing bracket
```

Comment: The closing bracket was in the second line of that block, but in the wrong position.
Thanks! I was drowning into a glass of water :)